# What's the Scala syntax for a function taking any subtype of Ordered[A]?

Tags: syntax, scala, subclass

I want to write a function that works on any Scala type with a total ordering (i.e. I can use '<' on it).  What's the syntax for that?  The best I've come up with is

```
def lessThan[T <: Ordered[T]](x: T, Y: T) = x < y
```

That doesn't work, though, when I try using it from the REPL:

```
scala> lessThan(1, 2)
<console>:8: error: inferred type arguments [Int] do not conform to method lessThan's type parameter bounds [T <: Ordered[T]]
       lessThan(1, 2)
       ^

scala> import runtime._
import runtime._

scala> lessThan(new RichInt(1), new RichInt(2))
<console>:8: error: inferred type arguments [scala.runtime.RichInt] do not conform to method lessThan's type parameter bounds [T <: Ordered[T]]
       lessThan(new RichInt(1), new RichInt(2))
```

Essentially, I believe I want the equivalent of this Haskell code:

```
lessThan :: (Ord a) => a -> a -> Bool
lessThan x y = x < y
```

I'm using scala 2.7.3 on a Debian system.

What am I missing, and where?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The equivalent of Haskell's type classes in Scala is done via implicits.  There are two ways to do what you want

The first is with view bounds

```
scala> def lessThan[T <% Ordered[T]](x : T, y : T) = x < y
lessThan: [T](T,T)(implicit (T) => Ordered[T])Boolean

scala> lessThan(1,2)
res0: Boolean = true
```

The second is with an implicit parameter

```
scala> def lessThan[T](x : T, y : T)(implicit f : T => Ordered[T]) = x < y      
lessThan: [T](T,T)(implicit (T) => Ordered[T])Boolean

scala> lessThan(4,3)
res1: Boolean = false
```

The former is syntax sugar for the later.  The later allows more flexibility.

Comment: Why do you have to bring the implicit in explicitly as a parameter to the method?  If the scala-runtime knows how to implicitly convert T to Ordered[T] why do I need to list an implicit parameter?  Thanks!

Comment: First, you can't just convert any T to an Ordered[T].  For instance, define an ordering over (Int => Int).  Second, when conversion is possible, the runtime doesn't know how to convert.  Instead, the compiler knows how to insert a function to do the conversion at runtime.

Comment: looks like the first method is deprecated [SI-7629](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7629)